# Basic Gamma functions identities not verified with Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Mathematica V10 does not return `True` to the following lines of code:

```
Simplify[Gamma[z] == (z - 1)!, Element[z, Integers] && z > 0]
Simplify[(Gamma[1 - z] Gamma[z]) == Pi/Sin[ Pi z] , 
         Element[z, Complexes] && (0 < Re[z] < 1)]
```

As I cannot believe that MMA10 does not know about these identities I wonder where are the  mistakes in my code which is structurally identical to a line  such as:

```
 Simplify[Abs[x] == x, x > 0]
```

which returns `True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) instead:

```
FullSimplify[Gamma[z] == (z - 1)!, Element[z, Integers] && z > 0]
FullSimplify[(Gamma[1 - z] Gamma[z]) == Pi/Sin[ Pi z] , 
             Element[z, Complexes] && (0 < Re[z] < 1)]
```

`FullSimplify` does more transformations as explained in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html).